# Limiting jquery .each to only images in #main section

Tags: jquery, each, attr

I want to set the Title attribute to images inside my #main and filling this title with text "Click for fullscreen". Even if there is no title definied i want to set.
Reason: tooltip needs a title to display.

This code i used in my custom.js file. It's working but sets the title attribute to all images, also in sliders and left or right columns etc.

How can i limit the routine to only the imgaes present in de #main off the webpages?

Used code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
            jQuery("img").each(function(){
                var Titel = jQuery(this).attr('src');
                jQuery(this).attr("title", "Click for fullscreen")
            });
        });
```

Adding #main selector in this way jQuery("#main, img")..... didn't work.

Please advise.

Comment: `,` in selector means "all" - instead, use a space ` ` which means *descendants*: `jQuery("#main img")`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Comment: What you're really dealing with here are CSS selectors, so referring to documentation and discussions of them is a good idea.